# Quantity / Performance Test

Tags: visual-studio-2008, continuous-integration, automated-tests, integration-testing

I don't know the name of it, but I want to run a test say 10,0000 to 100,000 times to test for variations in performance. For example I want to test the speed variation between json and xml. I am using visual studio. Is there any tool that will allow me to run my code this amount of times and collect the statistics? Please help me ASAP. THANKS!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have thought any decent profiler (e.g. [ANTS](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=unmet_need&utm_campaign=antsperformanceprofiler&gclid=CNaNs6Pi4aICFQGY2Aod7HLkYw)) would do the job.  You run your code in a loop and the profiler should give information on the performance statistics.

Answer (score 0):

I think its simply called "iterations" (Performance or load testing is when the number of users/ parallel operations are varied)

Doubts if visual studio will help here. You need some testing tool.. or if you've written your own test scripts, you could have a loop with a configurable no_of_iterations